# Why is my Docker Container not assigned with an IP Address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-container

I started up a Docker Container using this command `docker run alpine /bin/echo 'Hello world'` which created a container when I looked within `docker ps -a`.

I grabbed the Container ID and tried to inspect the IP Address by executing `sudo docker inspect <container id> | grep 'IPAddress'` which returned the IP Address as empty / null.

Any idea why it is giving no IP Address when the container should be automatically assigned an IP Address once created?

Comment: Your image will echo and then exit (`docker ps` will not list it as running). `docker inspect` will also report it not running (status -> exited). I guess it briefly _had_ an IP address...

Comment: The IP address that would create isn't particularly useful; why are you trying to look it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image will echo the message and then *exit* (docker ps will not list it as running). `docker inspect` will also report it not running (status -> exited).

If you replace your command with:

`docker run alpine yes` (oh, yes... so the container keeps running)

The container will surely have a valid IP address until you `docker stop` it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so when I run a command of `docker run -t -i alpine /bin/sh` for the interactive container within alpine it still shows no IP Address and shows it as "Exited". Is there any way to see the IP within before it exits?

Comment: I don't know of any docker command that can help. If you really need this (why?) you can log it on a mounted file during container startup (i.e. `ip address >> /mounted/file`)

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at a random stopped container of mine, and it also showed an empty string for IPAddress, when I know for a fact it had an IPAddress while it was running.

It is almost certainly the case that the reason you have no IPAddress is that your container is not actively running. It immediately exists after echoing 'Hello world'.

Comment: Yeah seems this is exactly what happened. When I run a command of docker run -t -i alpine /bin/sh for the interactive container within alpine it still shows no IP Address and shows it as "Exited". Is there any way to see the IP within before it exits?

Comment: When I execute `docker run -t -i alpine /bin/sh` and Inspect that container, it does have an IPAddress. It also stays running. Are you sure you are not accidentally closing the container when executing docker inspect <container>?